# when we need to specify the data type in exec() function?

Tags: python-3.x, exec

I have a piece of code that has used python exec() function. data is saved as an array in a file and when exec() is used, data type is specified as dictionary. I can't quit understand what's the output

```
style = dict()
# test.py includes one 10 x 10 array 
with open('test.py')as output:
    exec(output.read(), style)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing empty `dict()` as `globals` argument for `exec()` `output` will not be defined when `output.read()` is executed. If you need to print the result of `output.read()` then you need to pass either `globals()` or `locals()` as second argument to `exec`. They return a dictionary containing objects available in global and local scope respectively. The new code may be:

```
style = dict()
with open('test.py') as output:
    exec("print(output.read())", globals())
```

or

```
style = dict()
with open('test.py') as output:
    exec("print(output.read())", locals())
```

Return value from exec statement is `None` so you need to use print to see the output of `output.read()`

Comment: so, when we use dict() as a data type, what I have in test.py will be printed as a dictionary instead of array (original data type)?